# running python directory in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, command

I am trying to learn to code by reading through simple python project, and
there is one thing I quite do not understand.

Pardon me if the question was not phrased correctly, I am not sure how to phrase otherwise ...

[image]

[image]

IN the Getting started instruction, the part "run python installer",
What does installer refer here? does it refer to the installer folder in the directory or some pre-defined python commands?

Also, if it refers to the installer folder in the directory, how is that running any executable, since it is the folder, not any particular file????

I would really appreciate if anyone could help. Thank you

PS. https://github.com/sukeesh/Jarvis
is the link of the github project I Was reading through.

Comment: `the part "run python installer"` tells you how: `On Windows run setup.bat`

Comment: so, it has nothing to do with the installer folder in the project directory? 
Thanks for the help !!

Comment: I got it. python installer runs the __main__.py code in the folder 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When it means python installer, it means the exe that installs python for you which you can get [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) depending on which version you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may run your python code via anaconda prompt which u can get [here](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) also u can download your python library to the anaconda navigator

You also edit your code using **Pycharm** code editor